# Restar porcentaje en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente Script (visto desde otra pregunta):

```js
let precio = 8000;
let descu = 15;

var total = precio*0.0+descu;
console.log(total);
```

Lo que no entiendo es porque me devuelve solamente el dato que esté en 'descu' también he intentado:

> var total = precio - descu%

Y devuelve **Undefined**

(El dato 'descu' viene desde un input, pero para simplificarlo lo puse directamente.)

Si alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo restar porcentajes en JavaScript agradecería sus comentarios y respuestas.

Comment: Esto ya no seria pregunta de programacion: `8000 * 0.0 + 15 = 15`. Porque todo numero multiplicado por cero es **cero**. Para sacar el total con descuento seria `8000 - (8000 * 0.15)` o `8000 * 0.85`

Comment: @JuanRivera Todo número multiplicado por 0 da cero, eso es correcto, pero aquí yo no estoy intentando eso, por eso formulé la pregunta.

Comment: Tu pregunta dice "Porque me devuelve solamente el dato que esté en 'descu'" y la respuesta es esa, por otro lado como dije, ya no seria pregunta de programacion sino de matematicas al querer sacar un porcentaje que en matematicas es como la respuesta que te di antes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let precio = 8000;
let descu = 15;

var total = precio - (precio * 0.15);
console.log(total);
```